# BST C# finding sum of all right childnodes (for <T> Generic)

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have a binary search tree with 9 nodes. that looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APEv0.png)

I have such a code for the Node

```
class Node<T> : IComparable<T>, IComparable
        where T : IComparable
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Right { get; set; }

        public Node(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        public Node(T data, Node<T> left, Node<T> right)
        {
            Data = data;
            Left = left;
            Right = right;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to find the sum of all it right son nodes. I have such a method , but it doesn't work for Generic :

```
public void SumNodes(Node<T> node)
        {
            if (node == null)
            {
                return ;
            }

            int sum = 0;
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            if (node.Right != null)
            {
                if (node.Right.Left == null && node.Right.Right == null)
                {                    
                    list.Add(node.Right.Data);
                }
            }

            SumNodes(node.Left);
            SumNodes(node.Right);

            sum = list.Sum();
           
        }
```

Do you know, how to make it work??

Comment: `public void SumNodes<T>(Node<T> node) where T : IComparable` perhaps

Comment: You can't do maths with generics. There's no guarantee that the types you're accepting define a `+` operator, and no way to invoke one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postorder traversal like this.

```
   public void SumNodes(Node<T> node)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        Node temp = node;
        while(temp != null){
          if(temp.left && !temp.left.visited){
              temp = temp.left;
              temp.visited = true;
          }   
          else if(temp.right && !temp.right.visited){
              temp = temp.right;
              temp.visited = true;
              list.add(temp.data);
          }
        }
       sum = list.sum();
    }
```